# NOSQLUnit-mongoDB-example

Tags: java, mongodb, junit

I want to find some example about NOSQLUnit-mongoDB.But,some resource in this github can't work.http://lordofthejars.github.io/nosql-unit/nosqlunit.html
there is my code :

```
public class WhenANewBookIsCreated {


    @Rule
    public MongoDbRule mongoDbRule = newMongoDbRule().defaultManagedMongoDb("test");

    @Test
    //@UsingDataSet(locations="initialData.json", loadStrategy=LoadStrategyEnum.CLEAN_INSERT)
    @ShouldMatchDataSet(location="expectedData.json")
    public void book_should_be_inserted_into_repository() {
        WeiboDao wdao = new WeiboDao("test");
        Weibo weibo = new Weibo("unitNosql",1);
        wdao.save(weibo.toDBObject());
    }

}
```

initialData.json & expectedData.json:

```
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("53ec6b92419d5d941c6ba8a3"),
  "content" : "hello",
  "type" : "s",
  "predictType" : null
}
```

Anyone can give me some example using junit about mongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find [here](https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit/tree/master/nosqlunit-demo/src/test/java/com/lordofthejars/nosqlunit/demo/mongodb),there is some demo about NoSQLUnit includes mongoDB,Hbase,etc.